# Django HttpResponseRedirect and NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls

I am trying to redirect to a new form page whose fields get automatically filled with the data sent from the view function.

My urls.py is:

```
url(r"user_dashboard/NewRequest/([\{.*\}])", views.request_form, name = "NewRequest")
```

The view function which is sending the data is present at:

```
url(r"user_dashboard/NReq", views.request_request, name="NReq"),
```

which calls the above url.

The return statement from my view function is:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(request_form, kwargs={"device_type":devicetype}))
```

But, I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /user_dashboard/NReq
Reverse for 'inventory_management_app.views.request_form' with keyword arguments '{u'device_type': u'Laptop'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user_dashboard/NewRequest/([\\{.*\\}])']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_dashboard/NReq
Django Version: 1.11.13
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'inventory_management_app.views.request_form' with keyword arguments '{u'device_type': u'Laptop'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user_dashboard/NewRequest/([\\{.*\\}])']
Exception Location: C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:  C:\Anaconda2\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.14
Python Path:    
['E:\\inventory management\\inventory_management_service',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Anaconda2',
 'C:\\Users\\Jaimik Jain\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinpty-0.5-py2.7-win-amd64.egg']
Server time:    Wed, 6 Jun 2018 07:48:44 +0000
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong present in the above code?

Comment: You're currently passing the request_form as the first argument to reverse for whatever reason. Read through reverse's documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse. You need to pass the name of the urlpattern or the viewname you're trying to match to reverse.

Comment: what's the value of `request_form`?

Comment: Looks like it's 'inventory_management_app.views.request_form' from the exception @Lemayzeur.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following regex expression `url(r"user_dashboard/NewRequest/([\{.*\}])", views.request_form, name = "NewRequest")` in your URL:

try with `re` group name:

```
url(r"user_dashboard/NewRequest/(?P<device_name>\w.+)", views.request_form, name = "NewRequest")
```

Make sure you have device_name as a default argument in your view

```
def request_form(request,device_name=''):
    '''
```